# PWA - How to hide button add to screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

I make react app from Create React App then use default config PWA. But i got confused how to hide button add to screen. Any one can help me? thank you
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent the installation:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
})
```

In addition you can save the installation event and create a custom install button:

```
let installEvent;
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  installEvent = e;
})


button.onclick = () => {
   installEvent.prompt()
}
```